# What is the most elegant way to remove a listener from a list from a callback

Tags: java, kotlin, listener, concurrentmodification

Suppose I have the following listener

```
interface MyListener {
    fun onResult(result: Int)
}
```

and that my class holds a list of this listener

```
val MyListenerList = ArrayList<MyListener>()
```

My doubt is: if someone that registered the listener wants to unregister it (remove it from the list) when the callback (`onResult`) is fired, what is the most elegant way to do it, having in mind that calling it directly while the list iteration is running will cause a `ConcurrentModificationException`?

Comment: What language are you using? Java?

Comment: I am using Kotlin :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't iterate over `MyListenerList`, make a copy of `MyListenerList` and iterate over the copy. That way the removal can occur on `MyListenerList` without causing a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

For example:

```
ArrayList(MyListenerList).forEach { it.onRemove(n) }
```

or

```
MyListenerList.toArray().forEach { it.onRemove(n) }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @hudsonb. I will just not mark it as correct yet because I wanna check if is there any other elegant way than that.

Comment: This is how it is commonly supported. Another option you could consider would be to use a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` rather than `ArrayList`.